# How to save drawing as Project file and restore before start drawing

Tags: java, android, path, drawing

i am creating a drawing app in android studio,
i want to save drawing as a project file in memory but i am not able to save android.graphic.path arraylist in project file,

can any body help me to save drawing as a project file and load again when i want to draw previews project.
here is souce code of [paintView.java](https://github.com/techwithkaushik/drawing-app/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/ask2784/drawingapp/PaintView.java)

i try to save pathList and paintList as a object by outputstraem and Gson but not success, always getting pathList as empty.

i am expecting that whole drawing save as project and reload when want to work on when i left it.

Comment: Your drawing should be a collection (graph?) of model objects. You use the data in the model objects to determine what drawing operations to perform on the `Canvas`. You save the model objects to a file (JSON or otherwise). Your drawing operations should be modifying the model objects in addition to (or instead of) the `Canvas`. Your model objects represent the drawing itself -- the `Canvas` is merely one representation of the drawing.

Comment: can't understand you

Comment: Perhaps you should start learning Android with a simpler project, or by reading a book, or by taking a course. There are also [many open source drawing apps](https://search.f-droid.org/?q=drawing&lang=en), and you could look to see how they approach the problem.

Comment: can you suggest any good book to lean android development or youtube channel?

Comment: I wrote [a lot of Android app development books](https://commonsware.com/catalog), and all of the existing ones are free to download.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: @CommonsWare i feel, it will take long time to learn android from scratch, can you please provide some code to solve my problem at time. I will learn android after few months later.

Comment: can anybody help me , about my problem?